# React navigation 5 - How to generalize navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Imagine this navigation system:

```
-TabNavigator (-Tab Navigator-)
  --HomeTab (Tab Screen)
    ---HomeStackNavigator (-Stack Navigator-)
       ----> Home (Stack Screen)
       ----> Likes (Stack Screen)
       ----> Profile (-Stack Navigator- (the same as "ProfileTab > ProfileStackNavigator"))

  --ProfileTab (Tab Screen)
    ---ProfileStackNavigator (-Stack Navigator-)
       ----> Profile (Stack Screen)
       ----> Likes (Stack Screen)
       ----> Followers (Stack Screen)
       ----> ProfileEdition (Stack Screen)
```

I am implementing a generalized component that can be in **"TabNavigator > HomeTab > HomeStackNavigator > Likes"** and **"TabNavigator > ProfileTab > ProfileStackNavigator > Likes"** (or wherever I want)

This component, when pressed, will push another profile screen, passing params through the navigation.

```
navigation.push("Profile", params);
```

The problem is that if I am not inside **"HomeTab > HomeStackNavigator > ProfileStackNavigator"** or **"ProfileTab > Profile"**, the navigation will not work correctly...
For example, if I am in **"HomeTab > HomeStackNavigator > Likes"**, when I press the component, it doesn't pass the params correctly. Instead, if I do

```
navigation.push("Profile", {screen: "Profile", params});
```

It works perfectly, but... then the navigation will not work correctly if I am in **"ProfileTab > ProfileStackNavigator > Likes"**

Any ideas how to generalize this navigation so that I can reuse this component wherever I want?

I have thought to do something like this:

```
   if (current route is not inside TabNavigator > ProfileTab > ProfileStackNavigator) {
       navigation.push("Profile", params);
   } else {
       navigation.push("Profile", {screen: "Profile", params});
   }
```

### My second option

My second option is to remove the Profile Stack Navigator from the HomeTab, and, instead, put all its screens as screens of the navigator, like this:

```
-TabNavigator (-Tab Navigator-)
  --HomeTab (Tab Screen)
    ---HomeStackNavigator (-Stack Navigator-)
       ----> Home (Stack Screen)
       ----> Likes (Stack Screen)
       ----> Profile (Stack Screen)
       ----> Followers (Stack Screen)
       ----> ProfileEdition (Stack Screen)

  --ProfileTab (Tab Screen)
    ---ProfileStackNavigator (-Stack Navigator-)
       ----> Profile (Stack Screen)
       ----> Likes (Stack Screen)
       ----> Followers (Stack Screen)
       ----> ProfileEdition (Stack Screen)
```

And then, I will perfectly be able to do:

```
 navigation.push("Profile", params);
```

But I am not sure if this is better because of the code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

you should use an `Stack Navigator` on top of your `Tab Navigator`

```
const TabNavigatorRoutes = () => {
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="HomeTab" component={HomeTab} />
      <Tab.Screen name="ProfileTab" component={ProfileTab} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
}

const StackRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="TabNavigator">
                <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigatorRoutes} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Likes" component={Likes} />                
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

then add your `HomeStackNavigator` and `ProfileStackNavigator` inside your components (like before)

Comment: I tried this way before, but the problem is that I want the tab on the top of the stacks (just because of look-and-feel)